# Why can't i switch stylesheets in iframe using Firefox 4?

Tags: css, iframe, tinymce, firefox4

I am using an iframe and i have a tinymce UI button. When the button gets pushed i remove a stylesheet from the iframes head (and i add another stylesheet). This works.
On second button push i remove the formerly added stylesheet. This works.
But when i want to insert the stylesheet which i removed on first button push it does not work.

It looks like i am only allowed to insert a stylesheet which has never been loaded in the iframes head.

**Does anyone know why that is?
Is there a workaround for this?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change the function used to replace the stylesheet.

Formerly, i used

```
ed.dom.loadCSS( ed.settings.content_css );
```

to insert a stylesheet into the editor iframe head.

Main developer of moyxiecode spocke confirmed that loadCss only loads a stylesheet once (it several times in the past)

Using this jQuery code instead of the above code works like a charm:

```
$('#'+ed.id+'_ifr').contents().find('head').append('<link href="'+ed.settings.content_css+'" rel="stylesheet">');
```